# wxpython graph is really small

Tags: python, wxpython

So I have made a little app and I'm trying to make it draw a graph.

I've been following the examples here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#Plotting, just so I could get a simple linegraph up and running.

It works, however the graph is very small (could be an issue with sizers). https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUM7K.png

Here is my code for the graph:

```
class PageTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        canvas = wx.lib.plot.PlotCanvas(self)
        line = plot.PolyLine([(1, 0), (1,5)], legend='', colour='gray', width=25)
        plotter = plot.PlotGraphics([line], 'Bar Graph', 'X Axis', 'Y Axis')
        canvas.Draw(plotter,  xAxis=(0,15), yAxis=(0,15))
```

If anyone could suggest a solution that would be great, thanks.

Edit: Solved

```
class PageTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.canvas = wx.lib.plot.PlotCanvas(self, 0, size=(400, 400))
        sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)        

        line = plot.PolyLine([(1, 0), (1,5)], legend='', colour='gray', width=25)
        plotter = plot.PlotGraphics([line], 'Bar Graph', 'X Axis', 'Y Axis')
        self.canvas.Draw(plotter,  xAxis=(0,15), yAxis=(0,15))
```

Comment: I suspect you're seeing the graph's default size. Have you tried either manually setting the size during the canvas' `__init__()` or putting it inside a sizer using the `wx.EXPAND` flag?

Comment: @acattle I have just tried that, however it doesn't work. I have found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600652/plotcanvas-on-a-wx-panel, which seems to have the same issue. But the solution is difficult because I have structured my app around this example: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Simple%20wx.Notebook%20Example

Comment: @acattle ignore previous response, I fiddled around with your suggestion and it worked. Editing OP now. Thanks.